# Noty.js - set width of noty object

Tags: javascript, css, noty

I'm trying to change width of noty window/notification to 800px but I can't.[This is window with default width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w8yq.jpg)

I add to my .css file:

```
.noty-message{
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
}
```

and nothing change. When I try to add

```
.noty_bar {
    width: 800px;   
}
```

then my window looks like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daq36.png). How can I set width of noty object?

Answer (score 2):

I'm you're using `layout: 'topRight'` and `type: 'alert'`, this will force them to be 800px wide:

```
#noty_topRight_layout_container,
#noty_topRight_layout_container > li,
#noty_bar, #noty_type_alert           {
    width: 800px !important;
}
```

If you want to change it for other layouts and noty types, you'll have to change the "topRight" and "alert" substrings, but this approach should work.